# Is it possible to use python GUI instead of Abaqus GUI Toolkit?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm very new in the python world I know some about command line commands and gui commands.
I've already succeeded in writing a working python script for Abaqus and now I want to add some GUI in it instead of changing the parameters in the text file everytime.

I discovered GUI Toolkit but it seems to difficult, for two reasons: 1) it doesn't seem to be portable; 2) I don't really like the code written by someone else, especially because most of the times it adds things that I don't understand and gives me error that I can't fix, maybe because the GUI Toolkit interface is not complete.

Here's my question.
Can I use python tk GUI for abaqus? Is there anyone who has tried it and can share some simple codes.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You gotta learn to understand others code otherwise good luck when working with a team!

Comment: @KDawG yeah, but in a team I can at least ask a real person what his code mean, and most of the times it is commented. Here it's not, even the error messages are with no sense

Comment: your one tough dude, at least do some open source stuff on github or bitbucket then you'll get to know how to understand others code. And believe me or not asking others what their code means is literally not a good idea on the **field** cause you'd be disturbing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in GUI modules give you full access to the CAE API and are based on THE FOX GUI. If you are just doing simple user prompts there are built in functions for user input that allow simple popup windows without all the hassle of coding GUIs. The functions return lists of user input or True/False depending on the function.  They are limited to only text IO but are good for most simple UI.

Look at 52.5 of the scripting users manual:
ex:
Single Input:

```
yournumber=getInput('Enter a number:')
```

Multiple Input:

```
yourInputs=getInputs(fields=('NODES', 'ELEMENTS'), dialogTitle='INPUT SOME ELEMENTS AND  NODES', label='here is the label on the prompt box')
input1=yourInputs[0]
input2=yourInputs[1]
```

Yes/No/Warning:

```
yourAnswer=getWarningReply('Out of disk space!\nOkay to continue', (YES,NO))
if yourAnswer==YES:
    do some stuff
elif yourAnser==NO:
    do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert in the topic, but I do have some experience with writing plug-ins for Abaqus.

You may want to look into using the RSG (Really Simple GUI) Dialogue Builder. It is under the plug-ins options on the Abaqus toolbar.

The RSG is a GUI for building GUIs based on Abaqus's customized version of the FOX Toolkit. It is limited compared to programming the GUI yourself, but has plenty of options for creating some useful plug-ins. I generally start writing a plug-in by using the RSG to develop the base layout of my GUI. If there are options that I wish to include in my GUI that are not included in the RSG, I just edit the python files generated by the RSG.

Responding to your original question about whether or not you can use tk in Abaqus; I have run scripts in Abaqus that calls for the tk file browser and it has worked successfully. I don't see why you wouldn't be able to register the plug-in using the FOX Toolkit and then call tk to open a GUI.

Hope this helps. I know this is an old question, but the responses were weak. Additionally, I know how hard it can be to find good help/information on Abaqus scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I have used tk GUIs with Abaqus but I find they don't ingrate that well and end up causing all sorts of strange errors (eg ignoring text input, windows hanging etc). If you are used to tk its not that much of a leap with the FX & AFX routines. I didnt know about RSG though and just had a quick play, liking it.

Comment: Can you be, please, more specific what you have used Python tk in ABAQUS environment for? What was the reason (limitation?) that forced you to look for something outside of ABAQUS GUI environment?

Comment: @Mike sorry this post is over 8 years old so I dont fully rememebr what it was for. I think I was making a front end to generate meshed convex particles, so a user could set a number of associated parameters.